# How to move an image to the right of other images with html

Tags: html, css

below is my photoshop image and I want my site to look like it. this is the site right now.

http://mossgraphics.net/jdv/explore.html

I would like to move the img of women in headdresses to the right.

Photoshop img

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/naMSf.png)

can someone help me with the my html and css code?

Comment: what have you tried? look into `float`s? better yet, try a plugin like [masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/).

Comment: The photo is in a div with the `aExplore` class; and all div's with that class have the `float: left` property. So two options: Either change its wrapper to a `bExplore` or add `float: right` to that div: `<div class="aExplore style="float: right"><img ...></div>`

Comment: Change the order of the sections in the html. Since they all have float:left, the browser is choosing their position based on the order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

new css should be...

```
.aExplore {
    float: left;
    width: 601px;
    height: 400px;
}

.aExplore:nth-of-type(even){
    float:right;
}
```

What is does is tell the browser that every other `.aExplore` should float to the right instead of the default of left.

EDIT: Made the width of `.aExplore` wider to fix alignment (in chrome at least)

Comment: Thank you that worked :) Where do I find this code? I did not see this in w3schools.

Comment: @Mossbit I find myself using css-tricks more than w3schools. https://css-tricks.com/pseudo-class-selectors/ is your specific link. If this solved your issue be sure to up-vote the answer and select it as the solution. (It's the proper way to say "thanks" here on SO.)

Comment: Thanks I am new to asking questions in stackoverflow and was unaware of the up-vote arrow. Thanks again

Comment: I just noticed there is a small gap. It looks like the image is pushed 1 or 2 pixels to far to the right. if i fix this with margin or padding it moves everything. do you have any more advice?

Comment: I updated the `.aExplore` and by making it wider this seems to resolve the issue.